# php: unexpected pack("N")/unpack("N") behaviour with negative number

Tags: php, 32-bit, pack, unpack

I have such script to pack and unpack a negative number:

```
<?
$from = -123456;
$to  = unpack("N", pack("N", $from));
echo $to[1] . "\n";;
?>
```

On an Linux host (RHEL 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64) with PHP 5.4.7 `$to[1]` has the same value as input (-123456)

On another Linux host (RHEL 3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64) with PHP 7.3.6 the `$to[1]` has value 4294843840.

What's wrong? Why PHP 7 is acting so?

Comment: You're packing a signed number using an unsigned format. I wouldn't expect the results to be reliable.

Comment: That code you wrote is a bug with undefined behaviour. The fact that it "works" on your 5.4 installation is another bug. You should fix one or the other, ideally both, but depending on this corner case of bugginess is the least advisable option.

Comment: I wasn't aware of such bug with php5.4
In this case I have another doubt: the binary file containing the value to be unpacked is written by a SOLARIS SPARC (little-endian) machine and read by a LINIUX I386 (big-endian) one.
So is correct that I should unpack with "N" option and if value is greater than 2^31 I should decrement by 2^32:
`
$from = -133000;
$to = unpack("N", pack("N", $from));
if ($to[1] > pow(2,31)) $to[1] -= pow(2, 32);
echo $to[1] . "\n";
`